# Xamarin - Button not enabling after filling in the EditText fields

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I've been trying to enable a button when a user has filled in every EditText field. I did it like this:

```
        bedrijfsNaam.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {
            if(bedrijfsNaam.Text != string.Empty && contactPersoon.Text != string.Empty && telefoonNummer.Text != string.Empty 
                && plaats.Text != string.Empty && postcode.Text != string.Empty 
                && email.Text != string.Empty)
                ableToNav = true;
        };
```

The code above has been aplied to every TextChanged event for every EditText.
The puprose of this code is that it checks if every EditText field has been filled in. But sadly my button stays disabled. This is how I try to enable the button:

```
if (!ableToNav)
    navNext.Enabled = false;
```

Can anyone please point me out my mistakes?

Comment: When and where are you using `if (!ableToNav) navNext.Enabled = false;`? Try to debug if that statement hits when an EditText has changed.

Comment: beneath the TextChanged events

Comment: It just came to my mind that it's the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to enable a button that is disabled, you need to set navNext.Enabled to true:

```
if (ableToNav)
  navNext.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

In order to make this work I have to put navNext.Enabled in the textchanged event. Because this event gets checked everytime the text changes. If you wont but navNext.Enabled in these events it will never tell the app that it's being enabled because everything has been filled in. The following code is the correct example:

```
        bedrijfsNaam.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {
            if(bedrijfsNaam.Text != string.Empty && contactPersoon.Text != string.Empty && telefoonNummer.Text != string.Empty 
                && plaats.Text != string.Empty && postcode.Text != string.Empty 
                && email.Text != string.Empty)
                navNext.Enabled = true;
        };
```

that boolean is also not needed.

Comment: The bool is useless because it's only being checked when the activity starts.